# jquery then and fetch src - upload images to server

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, promise

I want to pass a list of image files to the server at once.

This is my code, where the function `srcToFile` is for creating a new file as image.

```
var formData = new FormData();

// Iterate all td's in second column
$("#table-image tbody tr:not(:first-child)").each(function (index, value) {
  var blob = value.cells[4].innerText;
  var fileName = (index + 1) + ".jpg";
  srcToFile(blob, fileName, "image/jpeg")
    .then(function (file) {
      formData.append("file", file);
      alert(formData.getAll("file").length); ** // I know that I can use aJax jquery to pass one by one at here**
    }, function (error) {
      //
    });
});

function srcToFile(src, fileName, mimeType) {
    return (fetch(src)
        .then(function (res) { return res.arrayBuffer(); })
        .then(function (buf) { return new File([buf], fileName, { type: mimeType }); })
    );
}
```

How can I use `formData` in this case?

Comment: did you check the http request from your developer tools? is the image file included in your request?

Comment: What is expected result?

Comment: @Jesse I get "src" from column of table row (before bind to table: var src = URL.createObjectURL(file);)

Answer (score 1):

Put all the promises returned by `srcToFile` into an array, then use `$.when()` to wait for all of them.

```
var promises = $("#table-image tbody tr:not(:first-child)").map(function (index, value) {
  var blob = value.cells[4].innerText;
  var fileName = (index + 1) + ".jpg";
  return srcToFile(blob, fileName, "image/jpeg")
    .then(function (file) {
      formData.append("file[]", file);
    }, function (error) {
      //
    });
}).get();
$.when(promises).then(function() {
    alert(formData.getAll("file[]").length);
    return $.ajax({
        url: "yourURL",
        type: "post",
        processData: false,
        data: formData
    });
}).then(...)
```

Comment: Thanks @Barmar!
I tried, it shows length = 0. might I wrong something?
I debugged and saw formData.append ran after alert.